# How to access ReactJS property in JavaScript function

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I have a (possibly complex) JSON structure in my ReactJS property -- this.props.fieldsCollection. I want to get this object in a JavaScript function so I can iterate through it and set a dropdown with values in a React-Component.

I can't get the value out in JS function.

```
function getPropertyValue() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var data = this.props.fieldsCollection; //gives "undefined"
    });
}
```

I want to have the collection returned in "var data" and a way to iterate over it. I am fairly new to Web dev (so please be kind to my simple question :)))

---------------------Solution thanks to your answers --- this is for others what I did-----------

It is just setting up the values in a global- JavaScript variable from the render method of ReactJS.

Eg,

```
var fieldsCollection; // global JS variable


module.exports = React.createClass({
    displayName: 'SidebarHeader',
    render: function () {
        return (
            fieldsCollection = this.props.fieldsCollection, // setting the global variable value first when render is called
               <div className="sidebar-header">
                 <div  className="multi-select-field">

//incomplete React.createClass code …

function someJavaScriptFunction() {
    var index, length = fieldsCollection.length;
    for(index = 0; index<length; index++)
    {
        console.log(fieldsCollection.models[index].id); // testing code to iterate through the fieldsCollection ..
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a variable on the global scope and then set it's value in one of you component's events.

For example:

```
var varToRead = 0

var Hello = React.createClass({
    getInitialState : function (){
        varToRead += 1;
        return null
    },
    render: function () {
        return <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <Hello name="World" />,
    document.getElementById('container')
);

$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log(varToRead)        
})
```

Here `varToRead` is the variable you want to read from. And we are setting it's value on the `getInitialState` which serves as an example of a component's event.

You could see Component Specs and Lifecycle where I took the getInitialState example: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html

The running example is here: https://jsfiddle.net/c8x07p0s/

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Basically I overlooked the fact that JS should be able to access the React property once JS variable is set from React render. The code was the direction but your first line "You can create a variable on the global scope and then set it's value in one of you component's events." solved my problem. Cherx :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example.

```js
import React from 'react';

import JDropMenu from './common/jDropMenu';

let DropDownMenuSty = {
 fontSize: '1.2em',
 padding: '2px 2px 0 0',
 position: 'relative',
 right: '0',
 top: '0'
};

let options = [
 { value: 'new', label: 'New' },
 { value: 'edit', label: 'Edit' },
 { type: 'seperator', key: '100'},
 { value: 'moveUp', label: 'Move up' },
 { value: 'moveDown', label: 'Move down' },
 { type: 'seperator', key: '101'},
 { value: 'rename', label: 'Rename' },
 { type: 'seperator', key: '102'},
 { value: 'remove', label: 'Remove' }
];

class DropDownMenuRender extends React.Component {
 render() {
  let optionLabel = this.state.option.label;
  let optionValue = this.state.option.value;
  return (
   <div>
    <div id='DropDownMenuSty' style={DropDownMenuSty}>
     <JDropMenu options={options} onChange={this.onSelect} />
    </div>
    Label: {optionLabel}<br />
    Value: {optionValue}
   </div>
  )
 }
}

export default class DropDownMenu extends DropDownMenuRender {
 constructor() {
   super();
  this.state = {option: {}};
 }
 onSelect = (option) => { this.setState({option: option}); }
}
```

```js
import React from 'react';

let DropdownSty = { position: 'relative' };

let DropdownControlSty = {
 position: 'relative',
 overflow: 'hidden',
 background: 'transparent',
 boxSizing: 'border-box',
 cursor: 'default',
 outline: 'none',
 padding: '5px 5px',
 textAlign: 'right',
 transition: 'all 200ms ease',
 width: '100%'
};

let DropdownMenuSty = {
 backgroundColor: '#261a3b',
 boxShadow: '0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06)',
 boxSizing: 'border-box',
 fontSize: '.9em',
 lineHeight: '150%',
 marginTop: '-1px',
 maxHeight: '300px',
 overflowY: 'auto',
 padding: '8px 12px',
 position: 'absolute',
 right: '0',
 top: '100%',
 zIndex: '10'
};

let DropdownSeperatorSty = {
 backgroundColor: '#000000',
 height: '3px',
 margin: '3px 0',
 width: '100%'
};

let DropdownNoresultsSty = {
 boxSizing: 'border-box',
 color: '#ccc',
 cursor: 'default',
 display: 'block',
 padding: '8px 10px'
};

let DropdownOptionSty = {
 boxSizing: 'border-box',
 color: '#EEFFEE',
 cursor: 'pointer',
 display: 'block'
};

class JDropMenuRender extends React.Component {
 render() {
  let items = this.props.options.map((option) => {
   if (option.type == 'seperator') {
    return (<div style={DropdownSeperatorSty} key={option.key}></div>)
   } else {
    return (
     <div
      key={option.value}
      style={DropdownOptionSty}
      onMouseDown={this.setValue.bind(this, option)}
      onClick={this.setValue.bind(this, option)}
     >{option.label}</div>
    )
   }
  });

  let value = (<i className="fa fa-bars fa-lg"></i>);
  let menu = this.state.isOpen ? <div style={DropdownMenuSty}>{items}</div> : null;

  return (
   <div style={DropdownSty}>
    <div style={DropdownControlSty} onMouseDown={this.handleMouseDown} onTouchEnd={this.handleMouseDown}>
     {value}
    </div>
       {menu}
   </div>
  )
 }
}

export default class JDropMenu extends JDropMenuRender {
 constructor() {
   super();
  this.state = { isOpen: false, selected: {} };
 }
 handleMouseDown = (event) => {
  if (event.type == 'mousedown' && event.button !== 0) return;
  event.stopPropagation();
  event.preventDefault();
  this.setState({ isOpen: !this.state.isOpen })
 }
 setValue = (option) => {
  this.props.onChange(option);
  this.setState({isOpen: false});
 }
}
```